# SVG to PNG Conversion in javascript

Tags: canvas, d3.js, svg, png

I am working on d3.js charts. I have radar chart that I want to print in PNG format, but when I do conversion it shows nothing and when I save image it saved but totally black or some time gives error

I used two methods 
1. with simple code that found on google

```
 var $container = $('#chart');

    content = $container.html().trim();
    canvas = document.getElementById('svg-canvas');

// Draw svg on canvas
    canvg(canvas, content);

// Change img be SVG representation
   var theImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
   $('#svg-img').attr('src', theImage);
```

In this used Canvg library but it shows nothing and second method is

2

```
saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0], "diagram.png");
```

In this **saveSvgAsPng**  library but it gives  **Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.**

I searched but did not understand that what the issue is with the conversion of canvas to **PNG** is as **SVG** converts to Canvas but canvas did not convert to **PNG**

Comment: You can not convert a resource to a dataURL that does not come from the same domain or does not have the appropriate permissions in the response header. This includes files on your local drives. Search Tained canvas for more info.

Comment: @Blindman67, from what OP said, there is no sign of a cross-origin request. Najam-us-Saqib, could you show us the markup of your generated chart ? Also you can try [this script](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap) I wrote. Note that IE<Edge will taint the canvas too, but you could provide a workaround by asking the user to right-click the svg, "save-as",  'filename.png'

Comment: @Kaiido The error OP notes is `Tainted canvases may not be exported` this is due to a cross origin resource tainting the canvas.

Comment: @Blindman67 no, and that's my point. You can also taint a canvas on IE<Edge by drawing any svg image to the canvas, or on Safari 9 by drawing an svg image containing a `<foreignObject>` element. There are also some UA tainting the canvas with some video formats. Tainted canvas is a security measure, it is not a sign of cross-origin request.

Comment: We use a remote server to do d3 chart direct SVG to img and PDF conversion with canvas. Drop in Javascript on page for REST submit/result. Example here http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.d3Charts

Comment: I meant without canvas. it scraps the SVG and sends to a remote server to be formatted,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image you are trying to convert to SVG is comming from another domain, you can't use toDataUrl on it for security reason.

If you have control over the domain serving the image, adding a header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.domain-where-you-use-your-javascript.com
```

when serving the image file may fix this issues

(Obviously, replace the domain name by the correct one)